# How to pass stored variable as database using mysql?

Tags: perl

---

I have the following code and I need to pass a variable as database. Is it possible to pass a variable as database?

my variables:

```
my $num_site = join('_', 'rate', $site, '1m');
my $num_site1=join('_','rate',$site,'current');
```

my code:

Here I tried to pass the variable instead of giving database directly.Can I follow this method to pass variables inside the do connection instead of database name directly?Kindly help me to pass my variables($num_site) and ($num_site1) inside the database?

```
$DBH=DBI->connect($database) or die "cannot connect to the sql server\n";   
$DBH->do("USE $num_site");(can i use the variable like this to fetch the database).
#$DBH->do("use rate_bangalore_1m");
$stmt = "INSERT INTO $num_site.m_status(time,available,closed,used,busy,reserved,down) VALUES(\"$current_time\",\"$ma{'D'}\",\"$ma{'B'}\",\"$ma{'A'}\",\"$ma{'C'}\",\"$ma{'R'}\",\"$ma{'+'}\")";    
print "\n $stmt \n";    
my $sth = $DBH->prepare( $stmt );
$sth->execute() or print "Could not insert data";
$sth->finish;
$DBH->disconnect();
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is "yes". You can use your variables inside strings and they will be expanded successfully. But I suspect you know that as you are printing the contents of `$stmt` before using it.

The string that you pass to the `do` method and the string that you assign to your `$stmt` variable are both just standard Perl strings. DBI does nothing unusual with them. They will work exactly the same way as other Perl strings.

However, given that you are asking the question, I assume that it's not working as you suspect and you have forgotten to tell us what unexpected behaviour you are seeing. One possible problem that I can see it that your two database name variables might not be set to the values that you expect before you get to this part of the program. I'd try printing those as well, just to ensure they are set correctly.

Two suggestions (that won't necessarily fix your, unspecified, problem but will improve the quality of your code):

- I rarely see people running a `USE` statement in DBI code. That's because you can set the database as part of the DBI connection string. See the [SYNOPSIS](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::mysql#SYNOPSIS) in the documentation.
- Please don't put your column values directly into your SQL. Instead, use bind points and extra parameters to the `execute()` method. Like this:

  ```
  $stmt = "INSERT INTO $num_site.m_status 
           (time, available, closed, used, busy, reserved, down) 
           VALUES
           (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

  my $sth = $DBH->prepare($stmt);
  $sth->execute($current_time, $ma{D}, $ma{B}, $ma{A},
                $ma{C}, $ma{R}, $ma{'+'})
    or die $sth->errstr;
  ```

  Not only is this safer (it protects you from SQL injection attacks), but it is also easier to read. Note that I've also added an error message.